# Linked entity references in a content type

Tags: views, nodes

I am unsure if this is possible in Drupal 7, but here is my problem: I have 3 content types, A, B and C.

B and C refer to A through a field field_A (entity reference).

C refer to B through a field field_B.

When creating/editing B, I want the user to select one node A1 of type A, and then, select some node of type B that refer to the node A1.

For example, let's say I have these nodes:

```
- A1, A2
- B11, B12 referring to A1; B21, ..., B24 referring to A2
```

A user creates new content of type C, and selects A2: I want the user to be able to select items of type B among the list B21, ..., B24.

I started to use an entity reference view to populate the list of B in C, but then was stuck because it is not possible (or I could not manage to do it) to refer to a field of the edited content type.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you might be able to use (or adapt your use case to) the https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select module

Answer (score 0):

Actually, while looking at the hierarchical_select module, I found a module which is (almost) working - the ["Dynamic dependent fields"](https://drupal.org/node/2088519) module.

It does not work yet with multiple values though.

Answer (score 0):

When you create node reference you can choose a view to select the nodes which can be selected when creating the content. To be specific you can even pass views arguments:

[image]

Comment: This is true, but what I need is a *dynamic* view argument (since it depends on the value of another field of the content type)